# PHPExcel. Не определяется тип ячейки

Tags: php, дата, phpexcel

Всем доброго времени суток!

Читаю excel-файл:

```
    $fileType = 'Excel2007';    
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);    
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file);
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($page);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    foreach ($rowIterator as $rowIndex => $row) {
       $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
       foreach ($cellIterator as $columnIndex => $cell) {
          if(PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime($cell)) {
            $val = date('d.m.Y', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cell->getCalculatedValue()));
          } else {
              $val = $cell->getCalculatedValue();
       }         
    }
```

Вот только условие PHPExcel_Shared_Date::isDateTime не отрабатывает, хотя даже в  свойстве ячейки стоит тип "Дата".

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте убрать эту строку

```
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
```